# Javascript regex

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

Currently I have a basic regex in javascript for replacing all whitespace in a string with a semi colon. Some of the characters within the string contain quotes. Ideally I would like to replace white space with a semi colon with the exception of whitespace within quotes.

```
var stringin = "\"james johnson\" joe \"wendy johnson\" tony";
var stringout = stringin.replace(/\s+/g, ":");
alert(stringout);
```

Thanks
Robin

Answer (score 11):

Try something like this:

```
var stringin = "\"james johnson\" joe \"wendy johnson\" tony";
var stringout = stringin.replace(/\s+(?=([^"]*"[^"]*")*[^"]*$)/g, ":");
```

Note that it will break when there are escaped quotes in your string:

```
"ab \" cd" ef "gh ij"
```

Comment: Very clever. I like it. Have tried to break it with no success.

Comment: Thanks Tim. I updated a case when it will break. But the OP didn't mention escaped quotes could occur.

Comment: Good point. You could work around that like so:
`\s+(?=((?:\\"|[^"])*(?<!\\)"(?:\\"|[^"])*(?<!\\)")*(?:\\"|[^"])*$)`

But now that's *really* fugly.

Comment: Yes, but what about strings that have an escaped backslash right before the closing quote: `ab "cd ef\\" gh`? When escaped characters come into play, it is time to leave regex-land, IMO.

Comment: Oh, and b.t.w., JavaScript does not support look behinds, only look aheads.

Answer (score 2):

In this case regexes alone are not the simplest way to do it:

```
<html><body><script>

var stringin = "\"james \\\"johnson\" joe \"wendy johnson\" tony";
var splitstring = stringin.match (/"(?:\\"|[^"])+"|\S+/g);
var stringout = splitstring.join (":");
alert(stringout);

</script></body></html>
```

Here the complicated regex containing `\\"` is for the case that you want escaped quotes like `\"` within the quoted strings to also work. If you don't need that, the fourth line can be simplified to

```
var splitstring = stringin.match (/"[^"]+"|\S+/g);
```

Comment: You'll want to swap `[^"]` and `\\"` around. Otherwise the backslash which is meant as an escape is "eaten" by the `[^"]`. Or add the backslash in your negated character class. Other than that, your way is a more intuitive approach (and in case of escaped characters, a working solution). +1

Answer (score 2):

in javascript, you can easily make fancy replacements with callbacks

```
    var str = '"james \\"bigboy\\" johnson" joe "wendy johnson" tony';

    alert(
        str.replace(/("(\\.|[^"])*")|\s+/g, function($0, $1) { return $1 || ":" })
    );
```